# Completing the square at GCSE level 9/9

Tags: quadratics, factoring, completing-the-square

I am reading **page 42** of a revision booklet from 2015 called **GCSE AQA Mathematics Higher Level**, **Complete Revision Guide and Practice**, by CGP..

The topic is completing the square. Below is a copy of the question and the step-by-step instructions given by the booklet. I am having trouble following, so I hope someone here can explain each step.

Fractions are written as 5/2 etc...

**Write 2x² + 5x + 9 in the form a(x + m)² + n**

```
2x² + 5x + 9
2(x² + 5/2x) + 9
2(x + 5/4)²
2(x + 5/4)² = 2x² + 5x + 25/8
2(x + 5/4)² + 47/8 = 2x² + 5x + 25/8 + 47/8
                               = 2x² + 5x + 9

So the completed square is: 2(x + 5/4)² + 47/8
```

Please follow the same method my book does, even if it is not the most elegant.

Comment: See what you can do with $16x^2 + 40 x +72$

Comment: if it is all integers and $a x^2 + b x + c,$   we may multiply through by $4a$  to reach $4 a^2 x^2 + 4abx + 4ac.$ The thing you need to confirm is: $(2ax+b)^2 = 4a^2x^2 + 4abx + b^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x+m)^2$ will have the form $x^2+2mx+m^2$. Notice that $x^2$ is alone, no coefficient.

So the first step is removing the coefficient from the $x^2$ term.  
If we write $2x^2 + 5x + 9$
as $2(x^2 + 5/2x) + 9$, then we've accomplished that.

The term in the bracket looks like $x^2+2mx+m^2$ but is missing the $m^2$ part. 
If $2m=5/2$; that means $m=5/4$ and $m^2=25/16$

Thus we can write it as

$
\begin{align}
2(x^2 + \frac52 x) + 9 &= 2(x^2 + \frac52 x + \frac{25}{16} - \frac{25}{16} ) + 9 \\
&= 2(x^2 + \dfrac52 x + \frac{25}{16}) - \frac{25}{8}  + 9  \\
\end{align}$

Now notice that the term within the brackets is of the form $x^2+2mx+m^2$ which is essentially 
$(x+m)^2$ with $m = \frac52$